# "echo" not shown in php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to display some variables and forms like a inbox type messages with "echo".

The problem is that the echo is not displayed and don't know how to repair it.

When i click on subject field on the subject title should show the "echo" but it doesn't.

Bellow is the code:

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['msg_id'])){

    $get_id = $_GET['msg_id'];

    $sel_message = "select * from messages where msg_id='$get_id'";

    $run_message = mysqli_query($con, $sel_message);

    $row_message = mysqli_fetch_array($run_message);

    $msg_subject = $row_message['msg_sub'];
    $msg_topic = $row_message['msg_topic'];
    $reply_content = $row_message['reply'];

    //updating the unread message to read
    $update_unread = "update messages set status='read' where msg_id='$get_id'";
    $run_unread = mysqli_query($con, $update_unread);


    echo "
        <center><br />
            <hr>
            <h2>$msg_subject</h2><br/>

            <p><b>Message:</b>$msg_topic</p><br />  

            <p><b>My reply:</b>$reply_content</p><br/>

            <form action='' method='post'>
                <textarea cols='60' rows='10' name='reply'></textarea><br /><br />
                <input type='submit' name='msg_reply' value='Reply to this' />
            </form>
        </center>
    ";
}

if(isset($_POST['msg_reply'])){
    $user_reply = $_POST['reply'];

    if($reply_content!='no_reply'){
        echo "<h2 align='center'>This message was already replied!</h2>";
        exit();
    } else {
        $update_msg = "update messages set reply='$user_reply' where msg_id='$get_id'";

        $run_update = mysqli_query($con, $update_msg);

        echo "<h2 align='center'>Message was replied!</h2>";
    }
}

}

?>
```

Bellow is the all code from my_messages.php. I decided to put it here all the code to avoid any questions regarding missing code information. Maybe will help to get the error.

The problem is at the end of the code when i try to click on my inbox and the messages are not displayed when i click on the sender subject. The form is not shown with the echo function.

```
<?php

session_start();
include("includes/connection.php");
include("functions/functions.php");

if(!isset($_SESSION['user_email'])){

    header("location: index.php");
}
else{
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>



<html>


    <head>

        <title>Welcome User!</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/home_style.css" media="all">

    </head>


    <body>

       <!-- Container starts -->
       <div class="container">

           <!-- Header Wrapper Starts -->

           <div id="head_wrap">

               <!-- Header Starts -->
               <div id="header">

                   <ul id="menu">
                       <li><a href="home.php">Home</a></li>
                       <li><a href="members.php">Memebers</a></li>
                       <strong>Topics:</strong>
                       <?php

                       $get_topics = "select * from topics";
                       $run_topics = mysqli_query($con, $get_topics);

                       while($row=  mysqli_fetch_array($run_topics)){

                           $topic_id = $row['topic_id'];
                           $topic_title = $row['topic_title'];

                           echo "<li><a href='topic.php?topic=$topic_id'>$topic_title</a></li>";

                       }



                       ?>
                   </ul>

                   <form method="get" action="results.php" id="form1">
                       <input type="text" name="user_query" placeholder="Search a topic"/>
                       <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search"/>
                   </form>

               </div>
               <!-- Header Ends -->

           </div>
           <!-- Header Wrapper Ends -->

           <!-- Content area starts -->
           <div class="content">

               <!-- User timeline starts -->
               <div id="user_timeline">

                   <div id="user_details">
                       <?php
                       $user = $_SESSION['user_email'];
                       $get_user = "select * from users where user_email='$user'";
                       $run_user = mysqli_query($con, $get_user);
                       $row = mysqli_fetch_array($run_user);

                       $user_id = $row['user_id'];
                       $user_name = $row['user_name'];
                       $user_country = $row['user_country'];
                       $user_image = $row['user_image'];
                       $register_date = $row['register_date'];
                       $last_login = $row['last_login'];       


                       $user_posts = "select * from posts where user_id='$user_id'";
                       $run_posts = mysqli_query($con, $user_posts);
                       $posts = mysqli_num_rows($run_posts);

                        //getting the number of unread messages

                       $sel_msg = "select * from messages where receiver='$user_id' AND status='unread' order by 1 DESC";

                    $run_msg = mysqli_query($con, $sel_msg);

                    $count_msg = mysqli_num_rows($run_msg);

                       echo "
                            <center><img src='user/user_images/$user_image' width='240' height='240'/></center>
                                <div id='user_mention'>
                            <p><strong>Name:<strong> $user_name</p>
                            <p><strong>Country:<strong> $user_country</p>
                            <p><strong>Last Login:<strong> $last_login</p>
                            <p><strong>Member Since:<strong> $register_date</p>

                            <p><a href='my_messages.php?inbox&u_id=$user_id'>Messages ($count_msg)</a></p>
                            <p><a href='my_posts.php?u_id=$user_id'>My Posts ($posts)</a></p>
                            <p><a href='edit_profile.php?u_id=$user_id'>Edit My Account</a></p>
                            <p><a href='logout.php'>Logout</a></p>
                            </div>
                            ";

                       ?>
                   </div>

               </div>
               <!-- User timeline ends -->

               <!-- Content timeline starts -->
               <div id="msg" align="center">

                   <p align="center">
                       <a href="my_messages.php?inbox">My Inbox</a> ||
                       <a href="my_messages.php?sent">Sent Items</a>
                   </p>

                   <?php 
                   if(isset($_GET['sent'])){
                       include("sent.php");
                   }
                   ?>

                   <?php if(isset($_GET['inbox'])){ ?>


                   <table width="800" align="center">



                       <tr>

                           <th>Sender:</th>
                           <th>Subject</th>
                           <th>Date</th>
                           <th>Reply</th>

                       </tr>


                       <?php

                    $sel_msg = "select * from messages where receiver='$user_id' order by 1 DESC";

                    $run_msg = mysqli_query($con, $sel_msg);

                    $count_msg = mysqli_num_rows($run_msg);

                   while($row_msg=  mysqli_fetch_array($run_msg)){


                       $msg_id = $row_msg['msg_id'];
                       $msg_receiver = $row_msg['receiver'];
                       $msg_sender = $row_msg['sender'];
                       $msg_sub = $row_msg['msg_sub'];
                       $msg_topic = $row_msg['msg_topic'];
                       $msg_id = $row_msg['msg_id'];
                       $msg_date = $row_msg['msg_date'];


                   $get_sender = "select * from users where user_id='$msg_sender'";
                   $run_sender = mysqli_query($con, $get_sender);
                   $row = mysqli_fetch_array($run_sender);

                   $sender_name = $row['user_name'];

                   ?>


                       <tr align="center">

                           <td>
                               <a href="user_profile.php?u_id=<?php echo $msg_sender; ?>" target="_blank">
                               <?php echo $sender_name; ?>
                               </a>    
                           </td>
                           <td><a href="my_messages.php?msg_id=<?php echo $msg_id; ?>"><?php echo $msg_sub; ?></a></td>
                           <td><?php echo $msg_date; ?></td>
                           <td><a href="my_messages.php?msg_id=<?php echo $msg_id; ?>">Reply</a></td>

                       </tr>

                   <?php } ?>

                   </table>

                   <?php

                   if(isset($_GET['msg_id'])){

                       $get_id = $_GET['msg_id'];

                       $sel_message = "select * from messages where msg_id='$get_id'";

                       $run_message = mysqli_query($con, $sel_message);

                       $row_message = mysqli_fetch_array($run_message);

                       $msg_subject = $row_message['msg_sub'];
                       $msg_topic = $row_message['msg_topic'];
                       $reply_content = $row_message['reply'];

                       //updating the unread message to read
                       $update_unread = "update messages set status='read' where msg_id='$get_id'";
                       $run_unread = mysqli_query($con, $update_unread);


                       echo "<center><br/><hr>
                            <h2>$msg_subject</h2><br/>

                            <p><b>Message:</b>$msg_topic</p><br/>  

                            <p><b>My reply:</b>$reply_content</p>

                            <br/>
                                <form action='' method='post'>
                                    <textarea cols='60' rows='10' name='reply'></textarea><br/><br/>
                                    <input type='submit' name='msg_reply' value='Reply to this'/>
                                </form>
                                </center>

                            ";

                   }

                   if(isset($_POST['msg_reply'])){
                       $user_reply = $_POST['reply'];

                       if($reply_content!='no_reply'){
                           echo "<h2 align='center'>This message was already replied!</h2>";
                           exit();

                       }

                       else{

                       $update_msg = "update messages set reply='$user_reply' where msg_id='$get_id'";

                       $run_update = mysqli_query($con, $update_msg);



                           echo "<h2 align='center'>Message was replied!</h2>";

                       }
                   }

                   }
                   ?>

               </div>
           </div>
           <!-- Content area ends -->

       </div> 
       <!-- Container ends -->    

    </body>

</html>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Are you saying that your echo is not displaying anything?

Comment: I assume this is just part of your code? Because otherwise it's quite logical it's not going to work.

Comment: Did you make sure the variable $_GET['msg_id'] is set? Please display it before the code and see if something is displayed

Comment: It will not display if the conditions in the if-statements aren't satisfied.

Comment: You need to use single quotes, echo '    ';

Comment: There's 1 to many closing brackets in that code. I'm also missing the database connection (missing include?).

Comment: hmm....tried to display the  $_GET['msg_id'] and does not shown. but if i hover over the "title subject" it shown in url msg_id=1 ... so i think that should work

Comment: is a part of the code because only that one is not working...the rest is working and the database connection is active and working

Comment: your if/else statement if broken. If `$_GET['msg_id']` is not set and `$_POST['msg_reply']` is set, the statement is executed but inside the statement you have `msg_id='$get_id'` ( = `$_GET['msg_id']` ).

Comment: If you do `echo $_GET['msg'];` and nothing is printed, it doesn't work, this is a fact. Please post the url in wich is `msg_id`. maybe the url is malformed

Comment: **Sidenote** You're wide open to SQL injection. I (or a malicious user) could retrieve and expose all of your data, or worse, drop your entire database. Please consider using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to safeguard you and your users.

Comment: the url wih the msg_id is www.site.com/my_messages.php?msg_id=1 when i hover the subject of the message

Comment: Try to remove whitespaces in echo.

Comment: May you share the url you are using to see this result?

Answer (score 0):

```
var_dump( $row_message)
```

after fetching from database to see what's in it.
Please consider changing this line

```
$row_message = mysqli_fetch_array($run_message);
```

To this

```
$row_message = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_message);
```

mysqli_fetch_array does not return associative array as you want to access further in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Please Make sure you are passing `msg_id` in query string like `someurl?msg_id=1`, else you won't see anything inside

```
if(isset($_GET['msg_id'])){
  /* get msg_id details from db and show */
}
```

this is because here we are checking if `msg_id` is set then show content. ;)

Comment: the msg_id is passed in the query string "<td><a href="my_messages.php?msg_id=<?php echo $msg_id; ?>">"